# Does calling multiple Google Cloud Run requests invoke new instances of the container

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I currently have a container in the Google Cloud Run service. When calling it multiple times in parallel using a HTTP GET request, I've inspected the logs and it times out due to exceeding memory usage which is currently set to 2GB.

I thought the container service invokes a new container each time therefore it should not matter the amount of requests made? This service works if called just once or twice.

Comment: Do you have a memory leak or memory management problem? One request, or one hundred, your app (container) should not be running out of memory.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm just spinning up multiple Puppeteer browsers which I think is causing the substantial memory usage

Comment: Without code or specific details on your application design, we can only make guesses. You will need to analyze memory usage and management in your application.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm looking to invoke many instances of Google Cloud Run, each launching Puppeteer and taking a screenshot. I cannot use Cloud Functions for this as I'm having to use a Google Chrome standalone in the Executable Path as Chromium doesn't load video. So for example, I will make 30 GET requests to this service, each spinning up Puppeteer which is causing it to run out of memory.

Comment: @Rake146 Please consider marking eamon1234 reply as correct, otherwise tell us what is your current problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to spin up a new container each parallel request, you need to set the concurrency to 1 (or as high as you can go without OOM). It defaults to 80.

```
--concurrency=CONCURRENCY
    Set the number of concurrent requests allowed per container instance. A
    concurrency of 0 or unspecified indicates any number of concurrent
    requests are allowed. To unset this field, provide the special value
    default.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've already set requests to 80 in Google Cloud Run, is this something I must also do in the docker file?

Comment: you need to set requests to 1 in cloud run, don't touch the dockerfile.

Comment: isn't the default at 80? What does cloud run do if I make multiple requests but I have this set to 1 in Google Cloud Run, does it form some sort of queuing mechanism?

Comment: the default is 80, however if you set it to 1, it will spin up one container per concurrent request which is what you are looking for, isn't it? You only get charged for every 100ms of active requests.

Comment: Concurrency and max-instances are two different parameters. Concurrency is the number of requests per container, max-instances is the maximum number of containers that will be active at any given time. If you set concurrency to 1 and all currently running containers are occupied, it'll spin up a new container (unless max-instances is reached in which case it has to wait until a container becomes available, potentially timing out in the mean time)

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification! Ben K & eamon1234 @BenK